# Unable to set width of button in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the following code to set the width of a button in my app:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int)(padding*density));
    b1.setLayoutParams (layoutParams);
    b1.setWidth((int)(buttonwidth*density));
```

Now the line `b1.setWidth((int)(buttonwidth*density));` is having absolutely no effect on the button's width. I tried increasing the width by 40 pixels, yet the button size stays the same. How do I increase the button width programmatically?

Here is the XML for the button:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login"
     />
```

And here is a screenshot of the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The setWidth is not working because you have already set the button to match it's parent width on the constructor, by setting its width to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Try changing the constructor to

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
buttonwidth*density, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: What is the value of padding? What happens if you set it to 0?

Comment: Daniel, Still no effect.